# Inconsistent Execution Time of RAND_bytes in OpenSSL during Benchmarking

Tags: c, performance, random, openssl, benchmarking

I'm benchmarking the RAND_bytes function from the OpenSSL library in C for cryptographic operations. However, I've encountered an issue where the execution time for this function is highly inconsistent. Every time I run the benchmark, the elapsed time varies significantly. This variability makes it challenging to obtain a consistent benchmark result. Is this variability in execution time an expected behavior for RAND_bytes?

Here's a simplified version of my code that measures the time taken:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

// Function to get the current time in microseconds
long long current_time_microseconds() {
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    return (long long)tv.tv_sec * 1000000LL + tv.tv_usec;
}

int main() {
    unsigned char buffer[128];
    long long start_time, end_time;

    start_time = current_time_microseconds();
    if (RAND_bytes(buffer, sizeof(buffer)) != 1) {
        // Handle error
        fprintf(stderr, "Error generating random bytes.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    end_time = current_time_microseconds();

    printf("Time taken (microseconds): %lld\n", end_time - start_time);
    return 0;
}
```

Is there an inherent reason within the RAND_bytes function or its implementation in OpenSSL that might cause such variability in execution time? And is there any way to mitigate this inconsistency to get more stable benchmark results?

Comment: When asking questions about performance then _always_ include information regarding which compiler and compiler options that were used. Because at least some 95% of these questions can be explained by incorrect benchmarking. I'm not exaggerating. For example by doing silly things like benchmarking non-optimized code.

Comment: How do you know the variability is in `RAND_bytes()` and not `gettimeofday()`?

Comment: Did you warm up your CPU frequency to max turbo by running a different program ahead of this one, like `warmup;  ./test` so there shell runs them back to back?  If not, you should certainly expect big speed variations.  In general, see [Idiomatic way of performance evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60291987) .  Also, I hope you're at least building with `gcc -O2 -fno-plt` to avoid dynamic linker overhead on the first call to a library function.

Comment: Benchmarking is difficult, especially with such a small amount of code.  Even experienced developers can end up timing the wrong thing.  e.g. https://lemire.me/blog/2022/08/09/hello-world-is-slower-in-c-than-in-c-linux/ makes a similar mistake as pointed out by @PeterCordes